# Caching data in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

A friend asked me to use `Output Cache` to cache data, that works good, but the thing is that I want to get data from the database and then interact with that data, I mean, I want to grab a huge data from the database, and then get only some data from that huge data according to the user activity dynamically.

```
 [OutputCache(Duration =600, VaryByParam ="none")]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
var result = context.People.ToList();
return View(result);
}
```

That's an example, but let's say that I want to use pagination for that data in my view, and I want to show every person according to the date birth, for example default page current week, with a link called 'Next' and other one called 'Previous' . When 'Next' link is clicked I want to display only the people which birthday is the next week, same thing with 'Previous', showing just people with birthday on the previous week.. 
But using Output Cache I'm displaying the same data all the time... Is it possible to do this interacting with the database only the first time, caching that data, and then interacting with that data and not read against the database again during the time I set on the duration?? Do you advise me to use another Caching Tool different than Output Cache?

Comment: Read about the `VaryByParam` property.

Comment: If your paging, then you will have a parameter in the method, so you cache when that parameter is the same

Answer (score -2):

Instead of caching the entire view, maybe you could just add the result to the session state?

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["peopleList"] != null)
    {
        return View((List<People>)HttpContext.Current.Session["peopleList"]);
    }
    else
    {
        var result = context.People.ToList();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["peopleList"] = result;
        return View(result);
    }
}
```

You can control how long session state lasts in your Web.config or through IIS.